# Обновление captcha Kohana 3.2

Tags: captcha, php, kohana

Помогите. Как реализовать кнопку под капчей "обновить картинку", чтобы без перезагрузки страницы появлялась новая капча?

**В контроллере**:

```
$captcha = Captcha::instance('default');

    $content = View::factory('index/auth/v_auth_register')
            ->bind('captcha', $captcha)
            ->bind('errors', $errors)
            ->bind('data', $data);
```

**В виде**:

```
<div class="number-box">
    <div class="top-box">
        <?php echo $captcha; ?>
    </div>
    <span class="gray-text"><a href="#">Обновить картинку</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью JQuery.
Сначала в элемент HTML добавляем обработку нажатия:

```
onclick="reload()"
```

И вот функция на JQuery:

```
function reload(){
id=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
$("img.captcha").attr("src","/captcha/default?id="+id);
}
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://wadya.pp.ua/2011/12/13/captcha-kohana/)

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!